# How to make common self-written scripts/functions available across conda environments?

Tags: python, cmd, anaconda, conda

I have some of my own python scripts which I wish to call from time to time for different projects which are located in folders all over my (windows) computer. The scripts just contain functions which I call from Jupyter notebook.

I had set them up successfully to be imported as modules using `import my_scripts` by placing them in a folder here `C:\Anaconda3\pkgs\my_scripts` and following the examples here: http://mikegrouchy.com/blog/2012/05/be-pythonic-__init__py.html
However I find they are only available when in the root `conda` environment. In my other environments created using `conda create new_env` I cannot access them.

I wish to know how to make them available in these environments, or if there are better practices that I should be doing - bearing in mind I have been programming in python a while but understand little outside a conda/jupyter notebook environment.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are several options. These are two of them.

### 1. Quickfix

Set the environmental variable `PYTHONPATH` to the directory that holds you packages. On Windows you can do this on the command line with:

```
set PYTHONPATH=C:\path\to\my\packages
```

This needs to be done for each new terminal window. For a permanent setting go to the control panel and search for "environmental variable". Add a new one
called `PYTHONPATH` and set it to `C:\path\to\my\packages`. Setting it for the current user should be enough (no admin rights needed). You need to start a new terminal window to pick up the new settings.

### 2. Nice Solution

You can [build your `conda` package](https://conda.io/docs/build_tutorials/pkgs2.html) and install it into each environment. You should give your packages version numbers. This has the nice  side effect that you can distribute your packages to others. It is bit more work though. But you will learn something new. :)